# When cloning on with git bash on Windows, getting Fatal: UriFormatException encountered

Tags: windows-7, bash, git, clone

I am using git bash

```
$ git --version
git version 2.9.3.windows.1
```

on Windows 7. When I clone a repo, I see:

```
$ git clone https://UserName@bitbucket.mycompany.org:5555/scm/repofolder/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
Fatal: UriFormatException encountered.
Fatal: UriFormatException encountered.
Fatal: UriFormatException encountered.
Fatal: UriFormatException encountered.
remote: Counting objects: 2666, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1426/1426), done.
remote: Total 2666 (delta 1378), reused 2112 (delta 1047)
Receiving objects: 100% (2666/2666), 1.53 MiB | 715.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1378/1378), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

I suspect that some other problems I am experiencing are related to this UriFormatException. Anyone know why the exception might be occurring and how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens when using GIT for Windows v2.9.3 and using a repository URL that includes a port number. Rollback to v2.9.2 or wait for a fixed version of GIT for Windows.

Comment: To rollback, can I just install 2.9.2 over 2.9.3 or do I need to uninstall 2.9.3 first? If I need to uninstall first, how can I do that?

Comment: The GIT for Windows v2.9.2 installer will simply do the downgrade. You can download that version here https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.9.2.windows.1

Comment: Confirmed. 2.9.3 is simply broken on Windows. 2.9.2 resolved the issues I was having.

Comment: 2.9.3(2) is now available which also fixes this issue https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.9.3.windows.2

Comment: This isn't the case for me, anyone with more information on the actual error and what causes it please share.

Answer (score 0):

when setting the proxy make sure the username and password does not have any symbols.
Clean password while setting proxy resolved the issue to me.

Answer (score -2):

Had the same issue.
just changed system git to embed git and started working.

Regards,
Basavaraj

Comment: Can you explain how to make this change for future readers?