# Github push, clone, and fetch functions in produce "TaskCanceledException" and "UriFormatException" errors

Tags: bash, git, clone

I've got git version 2.10.0.windows.1 (x64) and using the 'clone' or 'fetch' command I receive the message: "Fatal: TaskCanceledException encountered." although it appears to work successfully. Additionally, the push command produces the same with an additional "Fatal: UriFormatException encountered." error.

I read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1114193/when-cloning-on-with-git-bash-on-windows-getting-fatal-uriformatexception-enco) that this was a known bug in version 2.9.2 in windows but now I have version 2.10.0, has it still not been fixed?